# Firebase: Rule to prevent changes after a deadline

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have created wild Firebase rules and would like to add another check to them. I want to check two specific fields that can only be changed by the user if they are before the deadline.

The deadline timestamp is stored in the Firebase database as a "number" in seconds (e.g.: 1708074000):

- `/databases/$(database)/documents/app/config.deadline`.

The two fields to be checked are

- /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid).additionalGuests
- /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid).invitation

I have started with the following function, but I can't get any further:

```js
// Check if action is before deadline
function isBeforeDeadline() {
    let deadlineTimestamp = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/app/config).deadline;
    let isBeforeDeadline = deadlineTimestamp > request.time;
    return isBeforeDeadline
}
```

Here is my entire Firebase rule:

```js
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Check if "role" is not present in the request
    function isRoleNotPresent() {
      return !('role' in request.resource.data);
    }
    
    // Check if "role" is valid for normal users
    // Normal users can only have "guest" as their role
    function isRoleValueValid() {
      return request.resource.data.role == 'guest'
        || request.resource.data.role == 'invited'
        || request.resource.data.role == 'declined';
    }

    // Check if "role" is not changed
    // Normal users can't change their role
    function isRoleNotChanged() {
        let role = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role;
      return request.resource.data.role == role;
    }

    // Check if "role" is "guest"
    // Normal users can have "guest" as their role
    function isRoleGuest() {
      return request.resource.data.role == 'guest';
    }

    // Check if user is "admin"
    function isAdmin() {
        let role = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role;
      return role == 'admin'
    }

    // Allow the user to access documents in the "users" collection
    match /users/{userId} {
        // User can read their own profile
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;

      // User can delete their own profile
      allow delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;

      // User can create their own profile
      // But cannot set a different "role" (must be "guest"):
      // - Checks if no role field in request.resource.data
      // - Or checks if role is not modified
      // - Or checks if role is "guest"
      // - And checks everytime if role is a valid value
      // Users with "role" equal to "admin" can create any user's profile
      allow create: if (request.auth.uid == userId
          && (
            isRoleNotPresent()
            || isRoleNotChanged()
            || isRoleGuest()
          )
          && isRoleValueValid()
        )
        || isAdmin();

      // User can only update their own profile
      // But cannot set their "role":
      // - Checks if no role field in request.resource.data
      // - Or checks if role is not modified
      // - And checks everytime if role is a valid value
      // Users with "role" equal to "admin" can edit any user's profile
      allow update: if (request.auth.uid == userId
            && (isRoleNotPresent() || isRoleNotChanged())
            && isRoleValueValid()
        )
        || isAdmin();
    }

    // Allow access to the "config" document
    match /app/config {
      allow read: if true; // Everyone can read
      // Allow write only if user role from /users/{userId} is "admin"
      allow write: if isAdmin();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I separated each field to three condition, Then write rule for each one and added together.

1. The `invitation` field not exists and after update still not exists.
2. The `invitation` field is same value after update.
3. The `invitation` field is updated to different value and must before deadline.

The reason why 1 and 2 condition exists is if you are trying to update other field and number 3 condition could restrict that update.

```
function checkInvitationField() {
    return 
      // 1 is not exists
      (!('invitation' in request.resource.data) && !('invitation' in resource.data)) || 
      // 2 is same 
      (request.resource.data.invitation == resource.data.invitation) ||
      // 3 update before deadline
      (request.resource.data.invitation != resource.data.invitation && isBeforeDeadline());
}
```

Put it to profile path:

```
// User can only update their own profile
// But cannot set their "role":
// - Checks if no role field in request.resource.data
// - Or checks if role is not modified
// - And checks everytime if role is a valid value
// Users with "role" equal to "admin" can edit any user's profile
allow update: if (request.auth.uid == userId
      && (isRoleNotPresent() || isRoleNotChanged())
      && isRoleValueValid() 
      // I add it here, If needed add to create depend on your case.
      && checkInvitationField()
)
|| isAdmin();
```

I did some similar logic in my project, But I haven't test code above yet, So if you got any problem you can comment below, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I think thats a great way. I also think I can use your method to simplify my 3 checks for the "role" attribute and reduce the size of the larger update check. I didn't know that you can access the original field with "resource.data".

Comment: It works. I have adapted it a little to my needs, but it works. One problem was that I had saved a "number" as a timestamp for the deadline check. It is best to change it to a timestamp object in Firebase. The chek then is simple:

```js
// Check if action is before deadline
function isBeforeDeadline() {
  let deadlineTimestamp = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/app/config).data.deadline;
  return request.time < deadlineTimestamp;
}
```

Comment: I usually use `Timestamp.fromDate()` to create certain Timestamp object in javascript.

Comment: Ah yeah exactly what I found out. Previously, I had only saved the timestamp in seconds as a "number".

Now using it the way you described from here: ```import { Timestamp } from '@firebase/firestore'```